# YaHP Converter throws javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException

Tags: java, runtime-error, pom.xml, velocity, html-pdf

I just linked YaHP converter to convert my velocity template in PDF format.
And when I opened Swagger to run the API, all i got was this :

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException: Provider for class javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory cannot be found
```

Here is my pom :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.allcolor.yahp</groupId>
        <artifactId>yahp-internal</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-renderer</artifactId>
        <version>R8pre2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jaxen</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxen</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jtidy</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtidy</artifactId>
        <version>r938</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-play-plugin.org.allcolor.shanidom</groupId>
        <artifactId>shani-parser</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.17-patched-yahp-1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I havent used this class anywhere in my project and I have no clue on where to add what kind of dependency.

Its been 2 frustrating hours trying to google every possible solution but all in vain !

I dont know what else this demands. Please suggest me a solution

**Edit**
Here is my stack trace :

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory: Provider org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl not found
at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:239) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$300(ServiceLoader.java:185) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(ServiceLoader.java:372) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:404) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:480) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder$1.run(FactoryFinder.java:297) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.findServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.xml.datatype.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:268) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory.newInstance(DatatypeFactory.java:145) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.<clinit>(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:890) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.initConverter(DatatypeConverter.java:140) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(DatatypeConverter.java:341) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:29) ~[jjwt-0.2.jar:0.2]
at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtParser.setSigningKey(DefaultJwtParser.java:61) ~[jjwt-0.2.jar:0.2]
at com.wazootix.security.JwtTokenUtil.getClaimsFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:94) ~[classes/:na]
at com.wazootix.security.JwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(JwtTokenUtil.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
at com.wazootix.security.JwtAuthFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtAuthFilter.java:38) ~[classes/:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [YaHP pom.xml](https://github.com/agnhesi/yahp-converter-maven/blob/master/pom.xml) there's also [`xml-apis`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxmlapis1401jar.htm) jar that include the `javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeFactory` class you are missing

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Included it. Didn't work :(

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl

This is the runtime error I am getting

Comment: same error? have you checked you are not missing other dependencies?

Comment: Yes my friend I have checked it. I am getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl runtime error

Comment: Added the new pom and stack trace as well

Comment: it's not the same error... you are missing `xercesImpl.jar`

Comment: Done :) Its generating the pdf now. Thanks for your help :)